# Как преобразовать список в Python?

Tags: python

Как преобразовать:

```
[1234]
```

в такой вид:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: list(str([1234][0]))

Comment: спасибо работает...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Преобразовать в список можно так:

```
list(str([1234][0]))   //['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

p.s. Спасибо [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) за помощь